# Cannot Deploy Gadget-Application for Development and Testing

Tags: google-gadget, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I want to start developing a contextual gadget for GMail apps and have been following the  [guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/contextual_gadgets).

In the part about Installing and Testing the Gadget, it tells me to go `https://code.google.com/googleapps/console/a/{Domainname}` and upload the manifest file there. I have done this, the manifest file was accepted and I used the Deploy button.

I get to the page where it asks for the data permissions, click yes, and then get a Server Error. I have re-uploaded the manifest and triple-checked that the `<Url>` leads to a valid gadget xml. I get zero feedback about what the error could be, only that it's a Server Error and it happens every time I try. If the gadget XML is somehow invalid, I would not be able to check, as Google gives me no way to check such files for correct content.

Can anyone help, perhaps?